# XML error parsing SOAP payload on line 2: Invalid document end

Tags: php, web-services, session, nusoap

I'm new to web services.To learn about web services, I'm trying to create a web service that first has a login function which sets session. but when I want to use the information saved in session, I see this error:
"XML error parsing SOAP payload on line 2: Invalid document end "
I have to mention that if I set the user-id manually and do not use session,there wont be any errors!
could any one please help me find out whats wrong with my codes?
here are the client and server code:(don't care about some of parameters like $param in show_log function)

```
***server page:
    $server = new soap_server();
    $server->register('login');
    $server->register('show_log');
    function login($username, $password) {
    global $db;

    $result = false;
    $login_stmt = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
    $login_query = $db->query($login_stmt);
    checkDbError($login_query, __FILE__, __LINE__);

    If (mysqli_num_rows($login_query) == 0) {
        $result = FALSE;
    } else {
        $user = $login_query->fetch_assoc();
        $result = true;
        $_SESSION['id'] = $user['id'];
    }
    return $result;
}
function show_log($param) {
    $id = $_SESSION['id'];
    global $db;
    $log_stmt = "SELECT * FROM log WHERE `user-id`='$id' order by `date` desc";
    $log_query = $db->query($log_stmt);
    checkDbError($log_query, __FILE__, __LINE__);
    If (mysqli_num_rows($log_query) == 0) {
        $result = " No log was found";
    } else {
        while ($log_list = $log_query->fetch_assoc()) {
            $result[] = array("user_id" => $log_list['user-id'],
                "firstname" => $log_list['first-name'], "lastname" => $log_list['last-name'],
                "date" => $log_list['date'], "ip" => $log_list['ip']);
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
if (!isset($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA))
    $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA = file_get_contents('php://input');
$server->service($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);
exit();

**login page:
<?php
if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
    $client = new nusoap_client('http://localhost/webService2/server.php');
    $user = check_data($_POST['username']);
    $password = check_data($_POST['password']);
    $param1=array("username"=>$user,"password"=>$password);
    $response = $client->call('login', $param1);

    if ($response == FALSE) {
        ?>
        <div class="col-lg-12 ">
            <br><br><br>
            <div class="col-lg-4"></div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 message">
                <p>Invalid username and password</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php
    } else {
        header("Location:profile.php");
//        echo $response;
    }
}
?>
**profile page:
$param = array('word' => "aaa");
$response1 = $client->call('show_log', $param);
$error = $client->getError();
echo $error;
```

Answer (score 0):

This could happen when the page that you are accessing via your soap service contain some errors. In your php config file (**php.ini**) search for `display_errors = "On"` and change it to off (in windows it is the php.ini file but in in linux it might be different).